# C# Regex Replace similar words

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Need to replace operands named as `[WORD, WORD1, WORD2,..., WORDnnn]` in an expression like:

```
WORD-WORD1+WORD11
```

with operands named as:

```
[WORD_NEW, WORD1_NEW, WORD2_NEW, WORDnnn_NEW]
```

Some of the operands are not mapped, and those should not be replaced.

```
WORD-WORD1+WORD11 => WORD_NEW-WORD1_NEW+WORD11_NEW
WORD-WORD1+WORD11 => WORD_NEW-WORD1_NEW+WORD11 if WORD11 is not mapped.
```

Comment: Why not just use `string.Replace()`.

Comment: So you want us to do it for you?  Why don't you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: string.Replace won't work. Consider string.Replace("WORD","WORD_NEW"). It will replace 'WORD's in all operands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have map (presumably in form of `Dictionary<string,string>`) just run [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes delegate and check if mapping is present for each particular match:

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"WORD1", "WORD_NEW1"}};
var result = Regex.Replace("WORD-WORD1+WORD11", "WORD\d+", 
  match => mapping.ContainsKey(match.Value)? mapping[match.Value] : match.Value);
// result is "WORD-WORD_NEW1+WORD11"
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Regexp:

```
(WORD\d*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1_NEW
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(WORD\d*)";
        string substitution = @"$1_NEW";
        string input = @"WORD, WORD1, WORD2";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
WORD_NEW, WORD1_NEW, WORD2_NEW
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/2uTCjD/1

Test it: http://ideone.com/01Yxng